# Selecting a subset of data based multiple filters

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I am trying to get a subset of a larger Movies dataframe and I wanted to select all movies with from the USA and with a year between 2 dates.

I have written this statement:

```
usMoviesInRange <- movies %>% filter(country == "USA") %>% between(year, 1986, 2016)
```

but I get an error stating,

> Error in between(., year, 1986, 2016) : unused argument (2016)

can someone help me understand what is happening here or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `between` returns a logical value. You need to do something like:  `nycflights13::flights[between(nycflights13::flights$month,1,4),]` or use it within `filter`: `nycflights13::flights %>% 
  filter(carrier=="UA",between(month,1,4))  `

Comment: Just use `between` inside `filter`: `filter(country == "USA" & between(year, 1986, 2016))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend this option, you can put multiple arguments to `dplyr::filter`

```
usMoviesInRange = movies %>% 
    filter(country %in% "USA", 
           year > 1986, 
           year < 2016)
```

In case you use `dplyr::between` you must use it in this way:

```
country[between(x = country$year, left = 1986,right =  2016),]
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: To add to @danguloa, it seems that between sreturn booleans, which is why is must be indexed. Example: `x <- data.frame(C = c('US','US','MEX'), year = c(2015,2017,2019))
x %>% between(year, 2015, 2017) `

Comment: Thank you for this, I am coming from a C# background so some of this makes sense to me but the notation is what messes me up.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using `between(x, left, right)` correctly

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)
movies <- tibble(country = c("USA", "France", "USA", "USA", "USA"),
                 year =    c( 2000,     1995,  1935,  2019,  1990))
usMoviesInRange <- movies %>% 
  filter(country == "USA") %>% 
  filter(year %>% 
           between(1986, 2016)
        )
usMoviesInRange
```

to give

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 USA      2000
2 USA      1990
```

Comment: Curious why you used an additional filter and a pipe. Why not just add it to the first filter?

Comment: No particular reason - I just tried to fix the code and this was the first thing that worked.  Or I could have used `filter(between(year, 1986, 2016))` as Lunalo John did a couple of minutes after me  - the nice thing about R is there are several ways of doing the same thing

Comment: True story—I was just curious. I’m still learning so sometimes a small thing like that has more intention behind it than I realize. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 1):

`between` command is used in place of `>=` and `<=` e.g.

```
usMoviesInRange <- movies %>% filter(country == "USA") %>% filter(year>=1986 &<=2016)
```

can be rewritten as

```
usMoviesInRange <- movies %>% filter(country == "USA") %>% filter(between(year, 1986, 2016))
```